# Zend Framework URL view helper is not displaying full url?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, view-helpers

I have a url that looks like this:

```
/controller/action?query=foobar
```

In my paginator view script, I am calling the URL view helper to add the page number to the url:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next), null, false); ?>">
```

Passing `false` should make it so that the URL is not reset, but the URL being generated does not include the original query parameter:

```
/controller/action/page/2
```

...and it should be:

```
/controller/action/page/2?query=foobar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add the query string to the end of the URL that is created by the Helper. The helper's job is to create links based on *defined routes*. It will not maintain query strings because no route in Zend has a query string.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next), null, false); ?>?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the following format of the URL:

```
/controller/action/query/foobar
```

That should be compatible with the URL helper non-reset functionality and your code should work.